# Lazy GString in the current context in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline script. I need to do lazy evaluation on a GString. I understand that I can't use a closure inside a GString as I would normally do. However, if I create a closure that returns a GString (as suggested in the Jenkins documentation), it is evaluated in the context in which it was defined, not the current context.

I can't copy the code over from my corporate environment, so this is a made up example.

```
// At the start of the script
def deferredPom = {-> "${pom}"}

// somewhat later, inside a stage
def pom = readMavenPom
println "${pom}            // works, prints com.company:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, or whatever
println deferredPom.call() // throws MissingPropertyException because pom is not defined
```

The problem here seems to be that the parent of `deferredPom` is an instance of `WorkflowScript`, whereas the parent at the time it is being evaluated is an instance of `CpsClosure2`. Clearly, `pom` only exists in the context of the current closure.

I would like to evaluate `deferredPom` in the current context, not the context in which it was defined.

I have toyed with using `GroovyShell`, but firstly I can't make that work as I don't seem to be able to pass the right context (I'll probably sort that out), but secondly and most importantly, I don't want to have to permit scripts to execute `evaluate`.

Comment: Couldn't you just remove `def` to create `pom` in context of `WorkflowScript`?

Comment: No. As I said, this is a made up example. It is hugely simplified. Please suggest ways of evaluating the closure in the current context. If it isn't possible, I will have to find another way, but for now I would like to try to resolve this. Plus, what is this obsession in groovy/jenkins with the global context?! It flies in the face of all best practice.